# How to compile a small DSL?

Tags: python, dsl

I am writing a small Domain Specific Language for an application in Python (3.x). At the moment the language uses Python's interpreter to run the scripts, I would like to however to be able to compile the code into Python's bytecode, so that I could e.g. import it as a normal Python module.

Is there any way to achieve this, without actually having to go through the step of transforming my DSL-code into Python syntax?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "compile the code with Python". Regardless, you can only `import` Python code in a Python script. If you _convert_ or _translate_ the DSL into Python code and save that in a file, you should be able import it in another script.

Comment: Compile to what? Some custom byte/machine code? Python code? CPython VM's byte code? x86 instruction set / machine code?

Comment: @martineau At the moment I have an interpreter which runs on top of Python's interpreter, means a REPL where user can input code and get the evaluation's result. I want to be able to run the code e.g. directly from python, like compiling it to pyc so that python can also import it as a module.

Comment: @PeterBadida Compiling to bytecode (or Python code).

Comment: If you convert the DSL into equivalent Python code, it will automatically be converted into a .pyc when it's `import`ed. You could do this in advance by importing yourself once after the module is created. You could also do this by translating the code into byte code yourself, but I would prefer not doing that (it's not something Python is well-suited for doing and requires a lot of low-level knowledge).

Comment: So you are simply asking: how to write a compiler? It's a huge topic. You need to know precisely input, output and how to do transformations. Lots of work. Doable? Yes. Easy? Maybe, depends on how deep you want to go. Time consuming? Oh, definitely yes. Worth it? Probably not.

Comment: Again I'd like to emphasize that translating the DSL into Python will allow it to be imported into other Python scripts. This is the easiest path forward and you can always go back and optimize things later.

Comment: @martineau Thank you. I think this is perhaps the fastest way to go for me!

Answer (score 1):

For compiling into Python's bytecode you by default need two (three) things:

1. compliant Python code that can be parsed against [Python's grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html)

   if not for usage, then at least to compare against the AST if you generated it properly, if something's missing, etc

(1.5) Your DSL split into an abstract syntax tree (AST) - this is something Python does by default when you run (i.e. even import) the code/file.

2. [Python's compiler to its VM's bytecode](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/compile.c)

What you can do is either "compile" (translate) your DSL into an AST or into proper Python code and from there you can make Python interpreter (for the code) or Python compiler (for the AST) do what you want by e.g. calling Python's C API i.e. using Python as a C library instead of calling the interpreter as a binary.

For C API [start here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html), but currently I can't find any reference for the compiler, so in a "dummy" way you can simply include [`compile.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Include/cpython/compile.h) ([warning](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#include-files)) and then utilize the functions from [`compile.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Python/compile.c) if it is exposed in the library.

***If not***, you will need to compile Python manually (and perhaps even patch it), so these symbols are exposed and you can use them. However, this approach has a catch and that's - not using the public Python's C API may cause breaking your functionality eventually (symbols may change names, functionality or simply disappear), so if this approach is chosen, write tests and use specific commits, so you "seal" the version you use and after a while bump the commit, run the tests and see if it breaks (then fix).

Also, this is a mess of a topic because not a lot of people try to change or at least to access the default compiler, BUT:

- https://wiki.python.org/moin/AST
- https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (the good AST docs)

  - with Python's [`compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) compiling [to the bytecode](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tofrom.html#getting-to-and-from-asts) and calling with [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)
- [AST Transcript](https://talkpython.fm/episodes/transcript/152/understanding-and-using-pythons-ast)
- [PyCon 2010 AST topic](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2010/02/22/instrumenting_the_ast.html)

Other than that, try to reach out to CPython and PyPy maintainers:

- [mailing list](https://www.python.org/community/lists/)
- [IRC](https://www.python.org/community/irc/)
- [PyPy contact page](https://www.pypy.org/contact.html)

as PyPy did Just-in-Time compiling. But afaik [their code doesn't have pretty interface](https://www.pypy.org/download.html) so `tar` and `grep -r '<keyword [keyword ...]> <file or folder>` are your helpers here.